# Как в C++ задать случайное число ячеек в масиве

Tags: c++

Как в C++ задать случайное число ячеек в масиве. Когда я пытаюсь это сделать он выдаёт что переменая должно быть const хотя она и так const . У проекта нету не каких данных ведбь эта переменная должна определяться при первом запуске.

Comment: Создать динамический массив. Или использовать вектор.

Comment: Советую изучить применение STL контейнеров в C++ как можно раньше, это очень поможет вам в написании простого и понятного кода, а также ускорит ваше обучение. Изучить работу STL контейнера с точки зрения пользователя намного проще в начале, чем тему владения ресурсами, RAII и т.д..

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь std::vector вместо классического массива.
Вектор - своего рода динамический массив.
Пример:

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<vector>
int main(){
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));  // инициализируем генератор случайных чисел
    int randomNumber = rand();  // генерируем случайное число
    std::vector<float> randomVector(randomNumber,0);  // создаем вектор чисел типа float, содержащий случайное количество чисел равных нулю.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы используете `std::vector` вместе с сишным `rand`. Лучше тогда уж использовать `random` модуль